# Why wont chromedriver even start on windows 10 server?

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

currently I have a program that automates task filling.
I intend to run this program on my windows server I connect to via RDP however every time I run the program, selenium chromedriver seems to just go into an idle state and does nothing!

I have the latest chromedriver as of posting.

I've already tried a try-catch and display the errors however none seem to appear

My code for starting chromedriver:

```
                    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

                    var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
                    driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

                    options.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080");
                    options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
                    options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
                    options.AddArgument("--log-level=3");
                    //options.AddArgument("--headless");
                    options.AddArgument("--disable-notifications");
                    options.AddArgument("--disable-popup-blocking");
                    options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");
                    options.AddArgument("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
```

After setting the useragent and proxy I then try to navigate to the link:

```
                        //try timeout
                        try
                        {
                            chromedriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(links[rnd.Next(0, links.Length)]);

                        }
                        catch (OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException e)
                        {
                            chromedriver.Quit();
                            Console.WriteLine("[#] Proxy Timeout - Thread Restarting...", Color.Orange);
                            errors++;
                            loopt += 10;
                            continue;
                        }
```

Note this program works 100% fine on normal pc's (I've tried 4)

Please help! Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of Windows server?  There is 2008, 2012, 2016, 2019 there is no "10"  (please edit your question to fix this).  Also, the Server Core and Nano versions do not offer a desktop GUI.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/d188bf02b2f87897bd8a926b6ef03df2